# CSS to display a page scrolled to a specific element

Tags: css

Using a question on this site as an example, when a user first visits a website it could appear in three ways:

1. zoomed to fit the browser window, e.g. using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` (see illustration no. 1)
2. unscaled (see no. 2)
3. unscaled and scrolled to a specific element, e.g. the "Questions" link (see no. 3)

[image]

How can I achieve the effect shown in illustration no. 3, without using JavaScript? That is, how can I tell the browser to show the page not scrolled to the top, as is usual, but scrolled to a specific element:

[image]

An URL to an anchor such as `site.com/page.html#questions` would achieve the vertical "offset", but I want the scrolled state to appear even when the user comes to the page without following such a link.

Comment: I dont understand why u tagged this as CSS

Comment: @BatuZet Because I don't want a solution using JavaScript and can think of no other means, if not CSS. Feel free to change tags, but **do not add any JavaScript related tag**. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use javascript, then the only way to do it that I know is using `dart` https://www.dartlang.org/ but it will compile to javascript on some browsers. Css has no feature like this.